# Get all categories from Global in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

i'm trying to build a custom metabox using bainternets MetaBox class https://github.com/bainternet/My-Meta-Box/blob/master/class-usage-demo.php using a select element and populating it with all the product categories in my website. The problem is that the get_categories() method doesn't return anything and i suspect that is happening because it cannot see the scope of Wordpress posts. Is there a way to load the core at the time being or include it somehow? I'm writing in a separate file.

Update 1:
Through debuging i've seen tha it does not recognize my taxonomy "product_cat", it returns

```
array(2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid taxonomy" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. As i've discovered taxonomies aren't called until Wordpress init , so i've just had to make all my metabox construction action a function and add it to 'init' action.

```
add_action('init', 'add_custom__metabox',9999);
```